# Updating selected rows which are ordered

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-update

I need to make an update on selected rows which should be ordered by column which stores date.
The reason why I need such order is that I want to update rows with ascending values based on date order.

I'd love to get that in one statement if possible and I need that in my java code so I would like not to use cursors.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Oracle has ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION, so how about something like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyTable.Value = RowNum
FROM MyTable
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT ID, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserName ORDER BY MyDate) AS RowNum
        FROM MyTable AS InnerTable
    ) AS Hierarchy
        ON MyTable.ID = Hierarchy.ID
```

I had to make up some columns to make this work since your example does not seem to give enough of the schema. But, in general, something like this should work

Comment: I get error around SET teeest.order = RowNumb - "SQL command not properly ended". I tried with RowNum as well as RowNumb alias

Comment: Haha, oops. I edited my answer. I had omitted the subquery from table. Did you replicate that error?

Comment: Error at Command Line:2 Column:29
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: polecenie SQL niepoprawnie zakończone
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Which is around the first RowNum variable

Answer (score 0):

How could you set multiple values to a column in the SET clause?

Comment: I probably can't - I just want to achieve what I described and this piece of code is somehow description. I will edit it out because it might be misleading :)

Comment: Not downvoting, but please consider putting comments in the question comments, rather than adding them as answers.

Comment: Guys no down votes.. the question was edited.. and I dont have permission to comment here...